# JSON object and string function

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to call startsWith() string function on a JSON property value:

{"message":"xyzabc"}

```
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
var stringMessage = jsonResponse.message.toString();
if(stringMessage.startsWith('xyz')) {
...
}
```

but I get the error:

> Object xyzabc has no method 'startsWith'

How can I do that?

**The code is running on server side, Express on Node.js**

Comment: can you please post the sample JSON response text?

Comment: What is `.message` in your `jsonResponse`? It's hard to think out why something does not work, when you don't even know how does it look like!

Comment: Post your JSON Format.

Comment: In what browser are you testing this?

Comment: Are you using a browser that supports `.startsWith()`? Also, you're not operating on a JSON property value, you've called `.toString()` on an *object* property value, and are using `.startsWith()` on the result. [There's no such thing as a JSON object.](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: I added the JSON on question

Comment: The code is running on server side, Express on Node.js

Comment: Does `"test string".startsWith('xyz')` give the same error?

Comment: @nnnnnn I get error: Object test string has no method 'startsWith'. I solved using the solution with regex, and the solution with own coded startsWith() works well too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be happen that your browser does not support the `startsWith()` function so you can use use the `RegExp` to overcame this problem like this...

```
var jsonObject={message:"xyzHELLO"};
var regex=new RegExp("^xyz");
if(regex.test(jsonObject["message"])){
alert("hello");
}
```

[Live Demo HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lc06e7fy/1/)

**[EDIT]**

If you want to add the function `startsWith()` in your each and every `string` than you can add like this

```
if (String.prototype.startsWith !== "function") {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function (searching) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^" + searching);
        if (regex.test(this.toString())) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and after that you can use like this:

```
var jsonObject = { message: "xyzHELLO" };
if (jsonObject["message"].toString().startsWith("xyz")) {
    alert("start with");
}
else {
    alert("not start with");
}
```

**[EDIT]**

```
if (String.prototype.startsWith !== "function") {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function (searching) {
        if (this.toString().indexOf(searching) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As per the comment by @nnnnnn and I also think it is good practice if we use the native function of the `JavaScript`, Thanks @nnnnnn.

Comment: The code is running on server side, Express on Node.js

Comment: When you post the `question` at that time you does not describe it.

Comment: your solution works fine, thanks. I will try the other solution with own coded function startsWith() too.

Comment: Welcome. If you wan to use this code like `yourString.startsWith()` function than you can also add that function in the in the `String` class

Comment: If you're writing a generic startsWith() it would be safer to code the function with .indexOf(), because then you don't have to worry about the test string needing to be escaped for use in building a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, Js has startsWith function for the strings. However, using your own function to see if the string starts with the value should cause no error.

```
 function StartsWith(s1, s2) {
      return (s1.length >= s2.length && s1.substr(0, s2.length) == s2);
    }
    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
   var stringMessage = jsonResponse.message.toString();
   if(StartsWith(stringMessage,'xyz')) {
      //Doing Stuff!
    }
```

Comment: *"JS has no native startsWith"* - Well...[it does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith). (But it's not supported by IE.)

Comment: @nnnnnn i couldn't find it. Read more on using strings 


  http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/string4.shtml

Comment: @nnnnnn, well, i see. Thanks for the insights.

Comment: your solution works well, I mark the other solution with regex as first in time (1 min difference) only. Thanks.

Comment: @GPack hehe, well you chose a cannon to kill a fly :) . Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Please double check your input JSON. Your code works like a charm with a correct JSON input in `httpResponse.text`.

```
var json = '{"message": "xyztest"}';
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(json);
var stringMessage = jsonResponse.message.toString();

if(stringMessage.startsWith('xyz')) {
    alert('It works!');
}
```

Also please make sure the browser you are working in supports `startsWith` method. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_startswith.asp) you can find a list with all supported browsers.

If you need to work around the browser compatibility issues, you can use the widely supported `indexOf` method.

```
if(stringMessage.indexOf('xyz') === 0) {
    alert('It works!');
}
```

[HERE is a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2umjcmcb/1/) for both cases.

Comment: The code is running on server side, Express on Node.js

Comment: That's new, wasn't included in your original question. The code should work anyway.